# IntelliJ IDEA VM options

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I started creating a custom plugin using the IntelliJ IDEA. As soon as I extend an action from AnAction, override abstract methods and hit run plugin, I get Unable to start DebugAttachDetector, please add `--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED` to VM options

What is this. I tried adding this in settings/build, exec../compiler/java compiler under Override compiler parameters but still does not work. What am I to do :(

[image]

Comment: I think this warning is harmless and does not affect anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `runIde` has the type `RunIdeTask` which extends Gradle's [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task, you can use usual `jvmArgs` to configure launched JVM instance.

So, the following should remove the warning.
Groovy DSL:

```
runIde {
    jvmArgs '--add-exports', 'java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED'
}
```

Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks.runIde {
    jvmArgs("--add-exports", "java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED")
}
```

Not that it changes much as yole mentioned in the comment.

Comment: with the latest version of the gradle-intellij-plugin this needs to be `jvmArgs = ['--add-exports', 'java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED']` (for groovy DSL)